# Vue parent component unable to catch event emitted from the child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Child is emitting a custom event:

```
<template>
  <div id="controls-container" class="controls-container">
    <div class="control-button icon-zoom-in" @click="zoomHandler('+')"></div>
    <div class="control-button icon-zoom-out" @click="zoomHandler('-')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "ControlsContainer",
    methods: {
        zoomHandler(direction) {
            console.log("this will print");
            this.$emit('zoomHandler', direction);
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

Parent is not catching it:

```
<template>
  <div id="map" ref="map" class="navigation-map">
    <controls-container @zoomHandler="zoom"></controls-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ControlsContainer from "./ControlsContainer.vue";

export default {
    name: "NavigationMap",
    components: { ControlsContainer },
    methods: {
        zoom(direction) {
            console.log("will not print");
            if (direction === "+") {
                this.map.zoomIn();
            } else if (direction === "-") {
                this.map.zoomOut();
            } else {
                // Do nothing
            }
        },
    },

</script>
```

I have now read about 7 tutorials on this and they all show how it's done in the exact same way I am doing it. Considering the hours I've wasted on this I really hope it isn't something really simple...

Comment: this all seems good to me, can you check if event is actually emitting in vue devtools

Comment: Are the `<script>` tags missing from your child component or is that a typo? I have updated my answer considering this possibility.

Comment: That would be a typo, apologies. The child component in itself works.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the `<script>` tags are missing in your child component. Is that typo in your question? If they aren't there then that could explain the issue you're having.

Don't use Camel Case for DOM attributes, which applies to emitters and custom events as well.

In your child, refactor to:

```js
this.$emit('zoom-handler', direction);
```

In your parent, refactor to:

```js
<controls-container @zoom-handler="zoom"></controls-container>
```

Working Example via [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-gwwzc). *I had to open the preview in a new window/tab to display correctly.*

Comment: Tried that before with a single noun as the event name. No joy, same with your suggestion.

Comment: @Xvs Added a working example at the end of the answer

Comment: Slept on this and noticed that in your case parent is the vue app, so the root level. In my colleague's case who has a similar app, her parent is a view and child is a component, but in my case both are components on the same level so technically one is not the parent of the other. This would also explain why $emit.$root works but $emit.$parent doesnt - A is not catching the events from B because A is not it's parent. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I was right about Map not being the parent, the same is also evident from this:

    <div class="inner-container">
          <navigation-map></navigation-map>
          <controls-container><controls-container>
    </div>

However, nesting controls into the map caused some other issues like mouse clicks on the actual control buttons only firing on the parent (map) layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as your alternative.

```
<template>
  <div id="controls-container" class="controls-container">
    <div class="control-button icon-zoom-in" @click="zoomHandler('+')"></div>
    <div class="control-button icon-zoom-out" @click="zoomHandler('-')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
    name: "ControlsContainer",
    methods: {
        zoomHandler(direction) {
            console.log("this will print");
            this.$root.$emit('zoomHandler', direction);
        }
    }
};



<template>
  <div id="map" ref="map" class="navigation-map">
    <controls-container></controls-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ControlsContainer from "./ControlsContainer.vue";

export default {
    name: "NavigationMap",
    components: { ControlsContainer },
    methods: {
    },
    beforeDestroy(){
      this.$root.$off("zoomHandler")
    },
    mounted(){
      this.$root.$on("zoomHandler", (direction)=>{
        if (direction === "+") {
                this.map.zoomIn();
            } else if (direction === "-") {
                this.map.zoomOut();
            } else {
                // Do nothing
            }
      })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This actually works but I still fail to understand why simply emitting it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

These components are not nested, so Map is not actually the parent. Making it so causes some other issues. Not worh the hassle.